# Want to calculate length of the "runs" where values are the same in order not the total number in a python df

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
DateTime   Market Position  
2018-04-02 AD     -1  
2018-04-02 CD      1  
2018-04-03 AD     -1  
2018-04-03 CD      0  
2018-04-04 AD     -1  
2018-04-04 CD      0  
2018-04-05 AD      1  
2018-04-05 CD      0  
2018-04-06 AD      1  
2018-04-06 CD      1  
2018-04-07 AD      1  
2018-04-07 CD      1
```

I'm trying to calculate the number of rows where the position is the same (in order not total sum), for example for AD I'd expect to get [3,3] for CD I'd expect to get [1,3,2].

At first I thought a groupby would work for this but it won't give me the distinct count in order if the position repeats. I'm hoping there is a simple way to solve this.

Worth mentioning also that my actual df is very large with a lot more "Markets" so I probably don't want to hard code to just the 2 in the example.

Comment: Hi @Emily, and welcome to SO! Could you share with us what you've tried so far? Also, take a look at this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to help format your question for success.

Comment: Thanks @Kris I will check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are surely better ways to do this but here is a quick fix. For example market of AD:

```
# specify AD market positions in a dataframe
ad_df = df[df["Market"] == "AD"]["Position"]

# get the indices of the changepoints and the final index of the AD dataframe
runs = np.concatenate((np.where(ad_df.diff() != 0)[0], [ad_df.shape[0]]))

# the difference between current index and next index of changepoints is
# number of sames values until value changes
ad_order_count = [runs[i+1] - runs[i] for i in range(len(runs)-1)]
```

The values of `ad_order_count` would be:

```
[3, 3]
```

### Edit

For many markets and using a dictionary

```
markets = df["Market"].unique()

market_runs = dict()

for m in markets:

    temp_df = df[df["Market"] == m]["Position"]

    runs = np.concatenate((np.where(temp_df.diff() != 0)[0], [temp_df.shape[0]]))

    market_runs[m] = [runs[i+1] - runs[i] for i in range(len(runs)-1)]
```

The value of `market_runs` will be:

```
{'AD': [3, 3], 'CD': [1, 3, 2]}
```

Comment: Thanks @nepdavis I think this will work. However, my actual df is very large with a lot more "Markets" so I probably don't want to hard code to just the 2 in the example. I think I could use what you've provided and loop through the unique markets probably.

Comment: this was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df
      DateTime Market Position
0   2018-04-02     AD       -1
1   2018-04-02     CD        1
2   2018-04-03     AD       -1
3   2018-04-03     CD        0
4   2018-04-04     AD       -1
5   2018-04-04     CD        0
6   2018-04-05     AD        1
7   2018-04-05     CD        0
8   2018-04-06     AD        1
9   2018-04-06     CD        1
10  2018-04-07     AD        1
11  2018-04-07     CD        1

>>> df2 = df.groupby(['Market','Position']).size()
>>> df2
Market  Position
AD      -1          3
        1           3
CD      0           3
        1           3
dtype: int64
>>>
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct, CD should be 1 :1 , 0:3, 1:2

Comment: @Julkhar, I just checked to make sure my df matched the OP's question; I *think* it does. In this case, we have three instances of CD = 1 and three of CD = 0. Yes? OP, could you confirm and/or clarify what you're looking to count?

Comment: I also thought the OP wanted a solution @Kris provided, but I now actually think the OP needs the lengths of the runs of the same value, or the number of values between each change point. For CD, the "runs" are one 1, then three 0's, and then two 1's

Comment: @nepdavis - great insight! OP, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @nepdavis that is correct, I am trying to get the length of the runs for each. So for CD I expect 1 then 3 then 2

Comment: @Emily see my answer and check if that is what you need